# "Последний" или "крайний"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, этикет

Как правильно спросить, становясь в очередь: "кто последний?" или "кто крайний?"?

Comment: "Здравствуйте, за кем я буду?.." - "За мной"

Comment: за мужем.  
   
  
.

Comment: С исчезновением живых нерегулируемых очередей вопрос неуместен. Очередей, где люди знали в лицо и по имени всё ближайшее окружение собратьев, нет. Люди шли по делам и возвращались. Сейчас, видя хвост очереди, определить за кем встать несложно и странно задавать такие вопросы. Куда ещё не шло: вы — в этот кабинет, вы во 2-е окно?

Comment: А где это очереди исчезли? Вот к нотариусу недавно ходил. На почту. В поликлинику, в парикмахерскую. Да, есть электронная запись, но далеко не везде. Да даже в магазине бывает, что несколько касс, не разберешь, кто за кем.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вежливо будет спросить "кто последний?". Замена его на "кто крайний" произошла из-за профессиональных суеверий людей опасных профессий: летчиков, альпинистов и т. д. У них назвать кого-то "последним" считается дурной приметой.
Тем не менее, становясь в очередь, вежливее будет спросить "Кто последний?".

Comment: Я тоже считаю, что лучше спросить, кто последний?

Comment: Ха-ха, да, @саида, вы тоже так считаете.

Answer (score 2):

Хм-м. Возможно, "последний" и впрямь правильнее... 
Зато "крайний" безопаснее.  Лично знал человека, который после командировки за некстати, по его мнению, употребленное "последний" мог без дискуссий придать употребившему неравномерное ускорение, приложив силу к его массе...

@behemotus

- Жизнь не сводится к лингвистике.
  Даже к социолингвистике.
  Существует выражение "Кто последний?".  Достаточно широко употребляется. Существует синонимичное выражение "Кто крайний?", употребляется тоже достаточно часто. 
  Можно на основании более или менее убедительной казуистики объявлять одно правильным, другое не очень.
  А можно принять во внимание, сколько в нашем обществе групп людей, для которых силою вещей употребление одного или другого стало социальным маркером (свой-чужой). МЧС, МВД, МО... На Северах "последний" вообще употребляется реже и осторожнее.
  Повторюсь, может, "последний" и правильнее.
  Но, учитывая сказанное, вряд ли вежливее.

Comment: А давно это в лингвистике кулаки приравняли к аргументам?

Comment: Согласна с тем, что нужно уважать чужие суеверия. Это не вопрос лингвистики.

Comment: Уважать, если есть за что, нужно людей. В первую очередь — за преодоление суеверия.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите [здесь](http://www.gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_6_krainij/)

Comment: вроде тут пустые ссылки давать не принято?

Answer (score 0):

Обсуждали как-то в очереди этот вопрос, пришли к выводу, что лучше спросить: "За кем я могу занять?"

Comment: Неужели проблемы? В последнее (!) время хожу по врачам, везде спрашиваю "Кто последний" Пока не побили.

Comment: Я просто с 2-мя пожилыми профессорами стояла, они вели дискуссию в рамках приличия, просто, чтоб время скоротать.
   
А так, я тоже не слышала, чтобы у кого-то были проблемы из-за этого. Редко, но бывает, кто-нибудь скажет, что надо искать не "последнего", а "крайнего". Хотя сейчас слово "крайний" имеет и другое значение = "виновник каких-то проблем" или "тот, на кого можно взвалить всю ответственность за что-то проблематичное".

Comment: >Хотя сейчас слово "крайний" имеет и другое значение = "виновник каких-то проблем" или "тот, на кого можно взвалить всю ответственность за что-то проблематичное".

**"Кто последний, тот и крайний!"**

Я слышал такую шутку. Понравилась.