# "Кто последний" или "кто крайний"?

Tags: лексика

"Кто последний" или "кто крайний" в очереди?

Answer (score 1):

См. ответ [тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/159/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Answer (score 1):

У очереди два края, поэтому вопрос "кто последний"  - правильнее.